# How is it possible with input elements to get the respective parent form?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a bootstrap form

```
<form>
<div class='form-group'>
<input class='form-control' id='name'>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
<input class='form-control' id='email'>
</div>
</form>
```

So now I am getting the name element through its id:

```
let name= document.querySelector('#name');
```

now how to get the '' element through this 'name' element

In this case, it is easier to get the form (parent element of the parent element).
Suppose I have so much nested divs and it is so hard to keep track of the nested divs. so in such cases how to get the form element from the input.

Comment: [create a minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [closest() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) traverses the Element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor. If no such element exists, it returns null.

```js
let name = document.querySelector('#name');
console.log(name.closest('form'));

let name2 = document.querySelector('#name2');
console.log(name2.closest('form'));
```

```html
<form id="form1">
<div class='form-group'>
<input class='form-control' id='name'>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
<input class='form-control' id='email'>
</div>
</form>

<form id="form2">
<div class='form-group'>
<input class='form-control' id='name2'>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
<input class='form-control' id='email2'>
</div>
</form>
```